# JQGrid grouping while using loadonce issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, jqgrid, grouping

First timer here... so Thanks in advance.

I Have a JQGrid page.
This is my JQGrid (Latest version... Downloaded yesterday) setup:

```
$(function() {
    $("#list").jqGrid({
        caption: "My first grid",
        url: "demo_data.php",
        loadonce: true,
        datatype: "xml",
        mtype: "GET",
        pager: "#pager",
        height: "100%",
        autowidth: true,
        altRows: false,
        rowTotal: 2000,
        rowNum: 10000,
        rowList: [10, 25, 50],
        viewrecords: true,
        autoencode: true,
        colNames: ["Publisher", "First Name", "Last Name", "EMail"],
        colModel: [
            {name: "pid"},
            {name: "fname"},
            {name: "lname"},
            {name: "email", summaryType:'count',summaryTpl:'<b>{0} Item(s)</b>'}
        ],
        sortname: "pid",
        sortorder: "desc",
        grouping: true, 
        groupingView: {
            groupField: ['pid'],
            groupOrder: ['asc'],
            groupCollapse : true,
            groupText : ['<b>{0} - {1} Item(s)</b>'],
            groupSummary : true
        },
        ignoreCase: true
    });
    $("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{
        stringResult: true,
        searchOnEnter : false,
        defaultSearch: "cn"
    });
});
```

While loadonce is true, I Get an error on the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
```

This error stops the script on this line of code:

```
if(!grdata[kk - offset]) { break; }
```

On the GroupRender function.

When I make loadonce false, everything works fine with the grouping but I loose the awesome client side data manipulation.

This is the XML file I'm sending as data:

```
<rows>
  <row id = '1'>
    <cell></cell>DataA</cell>
    <cell>NameA</cell>
    <cell>LastNameA</cell>
    <cell>EMail A</cell>
  </row>
  <row id = '2'>
    <cell>DataA</cell>
    <cell>NameB</cell>
    <cell>LastNameB</cell>
    <cell>EMail B</cell>
  </row>
  <row id = '1'>
    <cell>DataB</cell>
    <cell>NameAA</cell>
    <cell>LastNameAA</cell>
    <cell>EMail AA</cell>
  </row>
  <row id = '1'>
    <cell>DataB</cell>
    <cell>NameBB</cell>
    <cell>LastNameBB</cell>
    <cell>EMail BB</cell>
  </row>
</rows>
```

Thanks in advance for your assistance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

loadonce: true does not seem to work with grouping:true if the datatype is xml

I had the same problem and I solved it by changing the PHP page that is called by the url property to return json and then changed the datatype property to json.